# Can I rename a namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

In C++ one can do this:

```
namespace qux = std::foo::bar::baz;
qux::CFoo BAR;
```

Can one do such a thing in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
namespace foo\bar\baz;
use foo\bar\baz as renamed;

new renamed\cFoo(); // Points to foo\bar\baz\cFoo()
```

See the [documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces may be aliased ([docs](http://php.net/namespaces.importing)).

The general idea is `use … as …;` as shown below.

```
use std\foo\bar\baz as qux;
qux\CFoo();
```

And here's a try-this-at-home example:

```
<?php
namespace std\foo\bar\baz {
    function CFoo() {
        echo 'hello, world';
    }
}

namespace {
    use std\foo\bar\baz as qux;
    qux\CFoo();
}
?>
```